# Why I can't display my images in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, manifest, mime-types

I'm trying to display two svg images to my page in react but it doesn't work, do you know why?

Here's the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "stone_black.svg",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/svg+xml"
    },
    {
      "src": "stone_white.svg",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/svg+xml"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

And here's where I implement it:

```
function Square(props) {
    // Elements that will display the game stones
    var srcToDisplay = ""
    if (props.value === "white") {
        srcToDisplay = "public/stone_white.svg"
    } else if (props.value === "black") {
        srcToDisplay = "public/stone_black.svg"
    } else {
        srcToDisplay = ""
    }
    return (
        <button
        className="squares"
        onClick={props.onClick}>
            <img src={srcToDisplay} />
        </button>
    )
  }
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using images in React, the general rule is to import the images into your component. I don't know the specifics of your setup, but if you're using most standard setups for React you should use something like this:

```
import stone_white from 'public/stone_white.svg'; // The relative path to the image 
import stone_black from 'public/stone_black.svg';

function Square(props) {
    // Elements that will display the game stones
    if (props.value === "white") {
        srcToDisplay = stone_white;
    } else if (props.value === "black") {
        srcToDisplay = stone_black;
    } else {
        srcToDisplay = ""
    }
    return (
        <button
        className="squares"
        onClick={props.onClick}>
            <img src={srcToDisplay} />
        </button>
    )
  }
```

Also, you probably don't want to be getting the images from the `public` directory. You might want to think about storing images in a dedicated directory in your `src` folder.